# Is it possible to combine data from different tables in one column

Tags: sql, postgresql, rdbms, postgresql-9.6

I'm trying to achieve the following JSON structure with a SQL-Schema:

```
"data_set": [
    {
    "id": 0,
    "annotation": "foo",
    "value": 
        {
        "type": "number",
        "value": 10.0,
        "unit": "m"
        }  
    },
    {
    "id": 1,
    "annotation": "bar",
    "value": 
        {
        "type": "text",
        "value": "Hello World"
        }  
    }
]
```

The tricky part is that I not only want to includes values of one type, but different types. My thought was to have different tables for each value e.g.:

```
numeric_value: id {PK} | type | value | unit

text_values: id {PK} | type | value
```

and include them in the data_set table via foreign key:

```
data_set: id {PK} | annotation | value {FK}
```

My problem is that I'm not sure how to reference ids from different tables in one column using keys, of if I'm taking a totally wrong approach in tackling this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in different ways. One of them is to use only one table, and have it defined in such a way that, when your `value_type` is `number` you are forced to fill in the values for `numeric_value` and `unit` (and nothing else), and when it is `text`, you must then fill in the `text_value` column (and *not* fill in the rest, but leave NULL).

This definition could do it:

```
CREATE TABLE data_set
(
    data_set_id integer PRIMARY KEY,
    annotation text,
    value_type text NOT NULL,
    numeric_value numeric,
    unit text,
    text_value text,

    /* Constraint to make sure values are consistent with definition */
    CHECK (CASE WHEN value_type = 'text' THEN 
              numeric_value IS     NULL AND unit IS     NULL AND text_value IS NOT NULL 
           WHEN      value_type = 'number' THEN 
              numeric_value IS NOT NULL AND unit IS NOT NULL AND text_value IS     NULL
           ELSE 
              false
           END)
) ;
```

The following inserts would be valid:

```
INSERT INTO 
    data_set 
    (data_set_id, annotation, value_type, numeric_value, unit)
VALUES
    (1, 'height', 'number', 10.0, 'm') ;

INSERT INTO 
    data_set 
    (data_set_id, annotation, value_type, text_value)
VALUES
    (2, 'brand', 'text', 'BigBrand') ;
```

These ones would not:

```
INSERT INTO 
    data_set 
    (data_set_id, annotation, value_type, text_value)
VALUES
    (3, 'brand', 'strange_type', 'misstake') ;

INSERT INTO 
    data_set 
    (data_set_id, annotation, value_type, text_value)
VALUES
    (4, 'brand', 'number', 'misstake') ;
```